# Laravel 5.4 Passport redirect after user registered

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, oauth, laravel-passport

When implementing Laravel 5.4 Passport and calling **/oauth/authorize**, with the requisite parameters, the Auth middleware redirects to **/login** when no session is found.  Upon logging in a redirect is made back to the **/oauth/authorize** route to complete the process.

This is working as expected.

However, if we need the user to instead register prior to authorizing then the intended **/oauth/authorize** uri is no longer redirected to after successfully registration.

I've poured through the middleware and the auth framework code.  Only coming up with `Redirect::intended()`, which is based on a session key of `url.intended`, but this is null even at the point of showing **/login**.

Any clues how I could redirect back to the **/oauth/authorize** page upon registration?

Comment: Short note, this could be related to what happens to the authorization request prior to being redirected to login, but I can't see where it might store that object.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I'm stuck on exactly this problem

Comment: Unfortunately not. We've had to keep our registration process completely separate until we can find a solution.  Which is a shame.

Comment: I have decided to ditch Laravel Passport and go with a custom solution. Which is to implement only the functions of OAuth that I need.

Comment: Feel free to share your solution. I'd be interested to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in RegisterController
you need to redirect it using redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()) instead of redirect($this->redirectPath())

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse([], 201)
            : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```